# How to type lambda expressions?

Tags: spacing, punctuation

In computer science and related field the identity function is sometimes written lambda x.x, the square function lambda x.x^2 an so on.
What is the correct way to typeset this in LaTeX? I have a couple ideas, but I don't know how they compare.

- `\lambda x.x`
- `\lambda x.\;x`
- `\lambda x\mathpunct.x`

Comment: The question is rather "_what is the correct way to typeset it?_" When you know *that* you can ask how to do it in LaTeX. So: How do textbooks typically write it?

Comment: @campa Well most textbook have a space after the dot (so option 2 and 3), but I am not sure what kind of space is semantically correct here (with respect to equation breaking, screen reader, this kind of stuff)

Comment: 0 := λfx.x   you dont need to put it in a maths environment.

Comment: I see examples where there is no space after the period. Can you point to some resource showing what you mean by “correct”?

Comment: @egreg This textbook for example uses both with and without space https://mroman42.github.io/ctlc/ctlc.pdf
I think a space is needed, I am not sure what is the "best" space to use

Comment: @egreg See my post. I give some history of the dot in lambda calculus. The comment is also sent to richardlll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are always no spaces before the dot and there are some spaces after the dot, we could use the `\ldotp`. For example,

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\[
\lambda x\ldotp M\to((\lambda x\ldotp M)N).
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output of `.` in the mathematical environments produces the dot without spaces before or after it. We can also define commands to produce a (lower) dot as a mathematical operator or relation.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\dotbin{\mathbin{.}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\dotrel{\mathrel{.}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{l}
\lambda x\ldotp M\to((\lambda x\ldotp M)N)\\
\lambda x.M\to((\lambda x.M)N)\\
\lambda x\dotbin M\to((\lambda x\dotbin M)N)\\
\lambda x\dotrel M\to((\lambda x\dotrel M)N).
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, I am writing a package which will contain both `\dotbin` and `\dotrel`.

---

---

**Some history of the dot in lambda calculus**

So far as I know, there are three kinds of dots used by scholars in lambda calculus: the first one is the dot produced by `\ldotp`; the second one is the dot produced by `.`; the third one is the dot produced by `\dotbin` used by Church who first introduced lambda calculus.

In my opinion the third one is the right interpretation. In [Church 1932](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968337), the dot is also used in other cases (cf. pages 356-358 of [Church 1932](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968337)).

[image]

In fact, Church borrows it from page 10 of [Russell and Whitehead 1910](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica) (Volume I).

[image]

Furthermore, Russell and Whitehead borrowed it from page VII of [Peano 1889](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN618102493?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B1%5D%7D). Peano used it as some kind of parenthesis.

[image]

Well, in all of them, it acts like some operators the same as the dot produced by `\dotbin`.

Comment: Why `array`? A single displayed expression should work.

Comment: @Sigur I delete it in the original example but add it back in another example.

Comment: Do you mean mathbin rather than mathop?

Comment: Yes, `\mathbin`. I revised it.

Comment: Why `\hbox`? That'll give wrong results in S and SS style.

Comment: `\mathop{{}.}` or `\mathop{\/.}`. But using `\DeclareMathSymbol` would be far more efficient.

Comment: @campa I delete the `\hbox`.

Comment: @campa While in that way, you should give the font in advance. Both way have their own advantages.

Comment: Thank you very much.